# Implementing Generic Interfaces and inheritance

Tags: java, object, generics, inheritance

Trying to implement a generic and inheritance classes in a Java Project.
For that reason I created the "Base" classes and Interfaces that will inheritance all the specific classes and interfaces.

I mean, I have a Base Interface

```
public interface BaseServices<T> {
    public boolean validate(T item, int id) throws Exception;
}
```

And a Base Implementation for that Interface

```
public class BaseServicesImpl implements BaseServices<BaseBO> {

@Autowired
BaseDao dao;
CategoryBO bo;

public BaseServicesImpl()
{
    this.bo = new CategoryBO();
}

    @Override
       public boolean validate(BaseBO item, int id) throws Exception {
       return dao.validate("name",item.toString(), id);
    } 
}
```

Where BaseBO is the business object that ALL the other objects will extend.

And then, for an specific object, I will have a particular Interface which extends the Base one.

```
public interface CategoryServices extends BaseServices {
    }
```

And its implementation:

```
public class CategoryServicesImpl extends BaseServicesImpl implements CategoryServices<CategoryBO> {

    @Autowired
    CategoryDao categoryDao;

    public CategoryServicesImpl()
    {
        this.dao = categoryDao;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(CategoryBO item, int id) throws Exception {
            return dao.validate("name",item.getName(), id);
    }
}
```

Where some object can implement the generic "Validate" method (which validates just the name) or extend it to what the class requiredpublic class CategoryServicesImpl extends BaseServicesImpl implements CategoryServices.

How can I make this work? Is it possible? I'm trying to do the most I can to reuse my code. Let me know if there is another way.

EDITED:
What I'm trying to do, is to have a base class with all the common method for all the classes, let say, the basic for create, edit, delete, get, getAll, etc. And then in each class I also can have and override for those method because in some classes they will be different, but in most, they will just do the same so it will call the generic ones that were defined in Base class.

Comment: "How can I make this work?" What exactly are you trying to make work?

Comment: This is probably abuse of inheritance and will give you headaches down the road. My advice: remove duplication by refactoring, rather than a big up front class hierarchy.

Comment: tl;dr, but at first glance it seems that at least `BaseDao`, and possibly `CategoryDao`, should also be typed, probably with the same type as the impl

Comment: You say that `CategoryServicesImpl extends BaseServicesImpl`, but why? I see no benefit from it.

Comment: @AustinD I added some extra information about what I want to do.

Comment: @munk sorry, I'm new in Java, I'm trying to do something I did in other lenguages, could you explain me a bit more about which refactor you think I can do? I'm just want to follow the best practises and I though this one was one.

Comment: @Bohemian CategoryDao extends BaseDao. They have the definition about how to do the create/save/update/get/validate/etc with Hibernate.

Comment: @Faabass You can do this with Java, just as with any other language. But it's bad practice **in any language**. It's a [code smell](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/). I suggest you implement your first service as simply as possible. Then do your second service and [refactor](http://www.refactoring.com/) to [remove duplication](http://blog.jbrains.ca/permalink/the-four-elements-of-simple-design), by moving to good [design patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns). Until you write that second service, [You aren't going to need it](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html)

Comment: @munk thanks for all the information, it's very useful for me. So your suggestion is not to use this "Common" method and interfaces to manage different type of business objects. I just include there the common functionality with non business object logic.
So, It is not a good practise to have a common class to manage the, let say, interaction different kind of objects. if you have any page were I can see some examples of what we are discussing here, that will be very useful for me.

Comment: @Faabass, the relevant links are in my comments in blue. I'm not suggesting it's bad practice to have a common class managing the interaction of objects. I'm saying it's bad practice to start with that before you need it. You're over-engineering your solution from the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve what you want, just with a couple of changes:

```
public interface BaseServices<T extends BaseBO> {

    boolean validate(T item, int id) throws Exception;
}

public interface CategoryServices 
    extends BaseServices<CategoryBO> {
}

public class BaseServicesImpl<T extends BaseBO> 
    implements BaseServices<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean validate(T item, int id) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }
}

public class CategoryServicesImpl 
    extends BaseServicesImpl<CategoryBO> 
    implements CategoryServices {

    @Override
    public boolean validate(CategoryBO item, int id) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The key is to let your generic `T` type be a descendant of `BaseBO`, and then adjust your `BaseServicesImpl` class to also be generic.

Comment: I marking this answers are correct because it works! but at the end I mix some of this answer with @munk 's comment to simplify some things

Answer (score 1):

**Caveat** [see my comment on good design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144268/java-implementing-generic-interfaces-and-inheritance?noredirect=1#comment58037949_35144268). Simplicity is the key to good software. Over-engineering is the road to madness.

If you have an interface and you need to share to the implementation of some methods between classes that implement that interface, you can use an [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) to implement the methods you need to share.

```
public interface Service<T> { 
    //note, interfaces are implictly public
    boolean validate(T item, int id) throws Exception;
    void foo();
    void bar();
}

public abstract class BaseService<T> {
    boolean validate(T item, int id) throws Exception {
        return false; // a default implementation
    }
    public abstract void foo();
    public abstract void bar();
}

public class FooService<T> extends BaseService<T>{
    public void foo() {
        println("foo"); 
    }
    public void bar() {
        println("bar"); 
    }
}
```

With Java 8, it's also possible to provide [default implementations in an interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).

```
public interface Service<T> { 
    boolean validate(T item, int id) throws Exception;
    void foo();
    void bar();
}
```

But beware, this is can lead to a sort of multiple inheritance which may make your code harder to reason about.

Comment: Should the BaseService implement Service<T>??

Comment: @paramupk There is no Service<T> for that class to implement. You choose one or the other unless you are paid by the line. Prefer interfaces over abstract classes.